# Why is os.listdir showing to a file while I set it to the directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, directory, subdirectory

So, I am making a python project that deletes files in a directory and my
code is:

```
    tmp_dir = r"C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\tmp"
    tmp_list = os.listdir(tmp_dir)

    for tmp_files in tmp_list:
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(tmp_dir, tmp_files))
```

and I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<my program's location>", line 9, in 
> shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(tmp_dir, tmp_files))   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py",
> line 737, in rmtree
> return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py",
> line 596, in _rmtree_unsafe
> onerror(os.scandir, path, sys.exc_info())   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py",
> line 593, in _rmtree_unsafe
> with os.scandir(path) as scandir_it: NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:
> 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\tmp\x64.json'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Can you please tell me what is wrong in my code? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shutil.rmtree` [deletes an entire directory tree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree).

To remove a single file, you can use [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove).

Comment: So, am I getting the error because I can't delete all the files in the directory?

Comment: No, you're trying to remove every single file (check your `for` loop) with `shutil.rmtree`, but if you need to use `os.remove`. If you just need to remove the tmp_dir, use rmtree on that.

Comment: Yes, I want to delete every single file in that directory.

Comment: To remove a directory and everything in it, call `shutil.rmtree` on the directory, once. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` returns all the files and directories in the path given. If you want to remove all the dirs you can filter by using `os.path.isdir` and then remove just directories.

You can try this code for getting all directories in a given folder:

```
tmp_list = [d for d in os.listdir(tmp_dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(tmp_dir, d))]
```

Answer (score 0):

os.listdir lists both files and folders

That rmtree you are doing only works on folders

So when the iterations reaches a file, it gives error

For both folders and files you need to do something like this

```
for temp_files in temp_list :
    if temp_files.isdir():
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(tmp_dir, tmp_files))
    else :
        os.remove("file path/filename")
```